# In Jquery, how do I wrap part of paragraph text inside span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I wrap the innerhtml found after a span in a paragraph inside a span. Better explained by example:

```
<p>foo <span>bar</span> baz</p>
```

I want to get:

```
<p>foo <span>bar</span><span> baz</span></p>
```

`baz` is possible marked up as well (ie can contain links etc).

Ive tried

```
$(p span).first().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();
```

But only gives me the inner span text of first span...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WpCsQ/)

```
var span = $('p > span:first')[0];
var target = [];
while(span.nextSibling) {
    target.push(span.nextSibling);
    span = span.nextSibling;
}
$(target).wrapAll('<span />');
```

Comment: Yup, since it's a new node. @Qtax What do you propose? Collect all DOM nodes till end of parent? Or is there an entirely different better way?

Comment: works great, even though I dont really understand how (especially the while condition), one line shorter and probably faster than my try - answer accepted - and +1 for "Qux", never seen that either ;)

Answer (score 2):

This might work

```
$('<span>').insertAfter('span')
$('</span>').appendTo('p')
```

You'll want to be more specific with your targetting of course.

Comment: Actually, I prefer Sahil's method.

Comment: It could be handy if you want to wrap text that has `<em>` or `<strong>` tags inside it, although Sahil's method might work just fine for that too.

Comment: it works for me, just `.append( 'some text' )` to `$('<span>')` or `$('<span/>')`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @Sahil Muthoo, @Saul and @puppybeard, unfortunately I had trouble getting your suggested answers working, so at last I came up with this which, allthough looks a bit overdone, works for my case.

See **[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/qekuW/5/)** over at jsFiddle.

```
var p = $('p').clone();
p.children('span').first().replaceWith('[split]');
var aParts = p.html().split('[split]');
var newP = $('<p>').text(aParts[0]).append($('p').children('span').first());
if (aParts.length > 1) {
    newP.append($('<span>').html(aParts[1]));
}       
$('p').replaceWith(newP);
```

Suggestion for cleaning up the above mess would be appriciated.